# get_posts query returning empty array over Ajax when not logged in

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am having trouble in getting WordPress ajax working when not logged in.  My get_posts query returns the correct posts when logged in.  The Ajax is called from the front end when the user clicks onto an author.  The author ID is passed in as a parameter through the Ajax function.

I have set up the `admin_url` and localized the script that the js is called from

```
function ajax_scripts()
{
wp_localize_script( 'meet_the_team_js', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'imgurl' => plugins_url( 'img' , __FILE__ )) );    
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_scripts' );
```

I have then added the `wp_ajax` (logged in users) and `wp_ajax_nopriv` (anon users) actions within the if `is_admin()` statement which I found on the wordpress documentation.

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_employee_recent_posts_ajax', 'employee_recent_posts_ajax' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_employee_recent_posts_ajax', 'employee_recent_posts_ajax' );
}
```

This is the employee recent posts ajax function

```
function employee_recent_posts_ajax($atts)
{
$html = get_employee_recent_posts();
die($html);
}
```

The full get_employee_recent_posts function is too long to post.  However here is the get_posts query that is causing the problem.  Note that the `$userid` and `$catid` variables contain the correct data when the user is not logged in.

```
$authorposts = get_posts(array('author'=>$userid, 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'order' => 'DESC', 'category' =>$catid));
```

If any one has any insight or ideas on how this could be fixed it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT:  Including part of the ajax request code.

```
jQuery.ajax({  
            crossDomain: true,
            type: 'GET',  
            url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,  
            data: {  
            'action': 'employee_recent_posts_ajax',  
            'userid': userid


},
```

Comment: what are u sending in parameter 'userid' when user is not logged in?

Comment: I think that `if ( is_admin() )` is not needed.

Comment: Sending the same data in userid when the user is logged in.  The data is the author_id of the author which is clicked on.  It is not the author_id of the current logged in user.  Hope this helps.  

Thanks for the info on is_admin.  Although I get the same results when I have removed it